# Dont seems "Android Project" Option from Eclipse->File->New->Project->Android->Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android and i have installed latest version of Android SDK
and eclipse.

When i try to create new project from
File->New->project->Android 
I don't see option "Android Project".I have installed eclipse-SDK-4.2-win32,ADT plugin 20.0.1 and Android 4.1 and I am using Windows 7

I have Option in New Project Pop up
      ->Android

```
  ->>>>Android Application Project
  ->>>>Android Project from Existion Code
  ->>>>Android Sample project
  ->>>>Android Test Project
```

There is no option Android Project

Are options "Android Application Project" and "Android Project" the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Android Project was recently renamed in Android Application Project.